# How can I set ChromeOptions to set the default directory and file name for downloading a WebPage using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, directory, selenium-chromedriver

Below example is simply opening google, and downloading the web page to pdf. I set the directory to C drive but the file is still showing up in downloads. Is there also a setting to set the name of file? Instead of Google, I would like the downloaded file to be labeled Test. Thanks in advance.

```
# Import Packages
import json
from selenium import webdriver

appState = {
    "recentDestinations": [
        {
            "id": "Save as PDF",
            "origin": "local",
            "account": ""
        }
    ],
    "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
    "version": 2

}

profile = {
    'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState': json.dumps(appState),
    'download.default_directory': r'C:\\'
}

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', profile)
chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
browser.get('https://www.google.com/')
browser.execute_script('window.print();')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing Webpage in a Specific Location in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66626315/printing-webpage-in-a-specific-location-in-selenium)

Answer (score 1):

It might not be exactly what you're looking for, but if you use `browser.save_screenshot('path/you/want/saved/to.png')`

Then you can take a screenshot directly through selenium and specify the place you would like to save the file.

You can also have a variable defining the path to the directory you want to save the screenshot in so it is more generalized.