Saving a page as pdf and SPECIFIYING WHERE THE DOCUMENT GOES
I want to save a page as a PDF. I am using Selenium in Python. I have the codes, and everything works. The only thing that I can't is not working that the PDF goes straight to the downloads folder. I would like to know if there is a is a way you can do:

specify the name of the file before saving it
control where the file gos

Here a snippet of the driver setting that I have:
ser_name = os.environ.get('username')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
download_path = f"C:\\Users\\{user_name}\\Documents\\mr\\"

# Define settings with the download path
settings = {
    "recentDestinations": [{
        "id": "Save as PDF",
        "origin": "local",
        "account": "",
    }],
    "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
    "version": 2,
    "saveToLocalPath": download_path
}

# Define preferences
prefs = {
    'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState': json.dumps(settings),
    "download.default_directory": download_path,  # Change default directory for downloads
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,  # To auto download the file
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True  # It will not show PDF directly in chrome
}

# Set up Chrome options
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')```


driver.execute_script('window.print();')


You might check this thread.  Looks like there's a different setting for kiosk printing folder ("savefile.default_directory"): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66626315/printing-webpage-in-a-specific-location-in-selenium
